# One-line "for" loop using list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, file-move

Someone has challenged me to create a program that sorts their pictures into folders based on the month they were taken, and I want to do it in one line (I know, it's inefficient and unreadable, but I still want to do it because one-liners are cool)

I needed a for loop to accomplish this, but the only way I know of to use a for loop in one line is list comprehension, so that's what I did, but it creates an empty list, and doesn't print anything from the list or anything.

What I'm doing is renaming the file to be the month created + original filename (ex: `bacon.jpg --> May\bacon.jpg`)

Here is my code (Python 3.7.3):

```py
import time
import os.path
[os.rename(str(os.fspath(f)), str(time.ctime(os.path.getctime(str(os.fspath(f))))).split()[1] + '\\' + str(os.fspath(f))) for f in os.listdir() if f.endswith('.jpg')]
```

and the more readable, non-list-comprehension version:

```py
import time
import os.path
for f in os.listdir():
    fn = str(os.fspath(f))
    dateCreated = str(time.ctime(os.path.getctime(fn)))
    monthCreated = dateCreated.split()[1]
    os.rename(fn, monthCreated + '\\' + fn)
```

Is list comprehension a bad way to do it? Also, is there a reason why, if I print the list it's `[]` instead of `[None, None, None, None, None, (continuing "None"s for every image moved)]`?

Please note: I understand that it's inefficient and bad practice. If I were doing this for purposes other than just for fun to see if I could do it, I would obviously not try to do it in one line.

Comment: If it's just printing `[]`, are you sure that the `if f.endswith` is doing what you want?

Comment: DO NOT use list comprehension unless you plan to use the result, it is not a way to one line a `for` loop. You should NOT one line this problem. If you want you can use `;` but that is poor practice.

Comment: Trying to shove your whole program into one line is like trying to shove your whole family into one pair of underpants. Maybe you can do it, but please don't.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse It's totally fine for golfing or when otherwise messing around.

Comment: @ruohola than just use `;` to write multiple lines in one. List comprehension consumes memory for each loop, best case it uses `None` for each call, worst case each call returns a large object thus making a large temporary list that is never used.

Comment: The efficiency of list comprehensions is primarily in creating a list, shortcutting the `lst.append(item)` step of a loop. If you're not trying to create a list, then a list comp is nonsensical. Because you're adding the return of a function to a list, and the function returns `None`, you get a list of `None`

Comment: @C.Nivs it is moving the pictures to the appropriate folder, so I assume that its working correctly.

Comment: @user2357112 lol, nice metaphor. I agree with you, and I have now realized that I require my program to be more complicated, so I'm expanding it to multiple lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is list comprehension a bad way to do it?

YES. But if you want to do it in one line, it is either that or using ";". For instance:

```
 for x in range(5): print(x);print(x+2)
```

And, by the way, just renaming a file including a slash will not create a folder. You have to use `os.mkdir('foldername')`.

In the end, if you really want to do that, I would just recommend doing it normally in many lines and then separating it with semicolons in a single line.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think to check to make sure that the folder was already there and create it if not, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is bad in two immediate respects:

1. You're using a list comprehension when you're not actually interested in constructing a list -- you ignore the object you just constructed.
2. Your construction has an ugly side effect in the OS.

Your purpose appears to be renaming a sequence of files, *not* constructing a list.  The Python facility you want is, I believe, the `map` function.  Write a function to change one file name, and then use `map` on a list of file names -- or tuples of old, new file names -- to run through the sequence of desired changes.

Comment: sorry, this might have been obvious in the answer, but what is the side effect?

Comment: `rename` is a side effect: you build a list, and file names magically change while you're doing that.

Comment: `map` isn't for side effects either. It's for creating iterators. It won't even *perform* any side effects unless you consume the iterator.

Comment: ohh, ok, that makes sense.